# Jquery if $this attribute selector contains a word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to use the jquery attribute contains selector on `$(this)`? I cannot find any examples. I am trying to see if input fields contain a certain word.

```
$("#form input").keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).filter( "[name~='someWord']" )) {
        console.log('yes');
    }
});
```

The code returns yes for all input even if they don't contain `someWord`.

Comment: The result of `.filter` is always a jQuery object wrapping 0 or more elements. It is always a truthy value, regardless of whether the filter returns 0 elements or not.

Comment: What's wrong with `$("#form input[name~='someWord']").keyup(handler);`???  EDIT: just rereading your question, your posted code seems complelty unrelevant to your expected behaviour, you don't want to check for name attribute but for input value instead (property, not attribute)

Comment: @CyberJunkie Is requirement of Question to include call to `jQuery()` with parameter `this` : `$(this)` and `jQuery( "[attribute~='value']" )` selector http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/ within `if` condition ? _"The code returns yes for all input even if they don't contain `someWord`."_ Can you create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: I'm not going to play a devil's advocate, but there is a small "war" between Neal and RajaprabhuAravindasamy (Raja for now) going here. I suggest to not look to the vote amount of the answer, but the answer *itself*. I have used Raja's fiddle (he placed that in his comment somewhere in this post) to show a comparision of both answers. [updated fiddle example with answer from Neal & Raja](https://jsfiddle.net/amy9aLus/3/). Please use the console (F12 on browser) to check the output and determine for yourself which answer is right one.

Comment: @KarelG in all cases Raja return `No` and for all mine return `yes`. interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `.is()` at this context,

```
if($(this).is( "[name~='someWord']" )) {
    console.log('yes');
}
```

Because `.filter()` would return a jquery object (element collection), and that would never be `false`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this even better with [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) in the event handler

```
$("#form input").keyup(function(evt) {
    if (evt.currentTarget.name.indexOf('someWord') > -1) {
        console.log('yes');
    }
});
```

This checks the `name` attribute of the actual DOM element and does not add the overhead of the jquery wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#form input").keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).filter("[name~='someWord']").length) {
        console.log('yes');
    }
});
```

or better:

```
$("#form input").keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).is("[name~='someWord']")) {
        console.log('yes');
    }
});
```